# Android TabHost - setIndicator method

Tags: android

I'm trying to create aplication interface using TabHost. Here is an example that I'm using: [example](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/)
I followed it step by step but I' m getting error in Main class that I can't deal with. Here is my code:

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class Main extends TabActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

TabSpec settings = tabHost.newTabSpec("Settings");

settings.setIndicator("Settings", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_settings_tab));
Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
settings.setContent(settingsIntent);

TabSpec recorder = tabHost.newTabSpec("Recorder");
recorder.setIndicator("Recorder", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_recorder_tab));
Intent recorderIntent = new Intent(this, Recorder.class);
recorder.setContent(recorderIntent);

TabSpec player = tabHost.newTabSpec("Player");
player.setIndicator("Recorder", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_player_tab));
Intent playerIntent = new Intent(this, Player.class);
player.setContent(playerIntent);

tabHost.addTab(settings);
tabHost.addTab(recorder);
tabHost.addTab(player); 
}
```

And for the following line:

```
settings.setIndicator("Settings",   getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_settings_tab));
```

I'm getting this errors:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
- Syntax error, insert ";" to complete FieldDeclaration
- Syntax error on token ".", { expected
- Return type for the method is missing
- Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
- The method getDrawable(int) is undefined for the type Main
- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
- Return type for the method is missing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all that code

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

TabSpec settings = tabHost.newTabSpec("Settings");

settings.setIndicator("Settings", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_settings_tab));
Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
settings.setContent(settingsIntent);

TabSpec recorder = tabHost.newTabSpec("Recorder");
recorder.setIndicator("Recorder", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_recorder_tab));
Intent recorderIntent = new Intent(this, Recorder.class);
recorder.setContent(recorderIntent);

TabSpec player = tabHost.newTabSpec("Player");
player.setIndicator("Recorder", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_player_tab));
Intent playerIntent = new Intent(this, Player.class);
player.setContent(playerIntent);

tabHost.addTab(settings);
tabHost.addTab(recorder);
tabHost.addTab(player);
```

inside the `onCreate()` method

As a result you will get this:

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;



    public class Main extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    TabSpec settings = tabHost.newTabSpec("Settings");

    settings.setIndicator("Settings", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_settings_tab));
    Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
    settings.setContent(settingsIntent);

    TabSpec recorder = tabHost.newTabSpec("Recorder");
    recorder.setIndicator("Recorder", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_recorder_tab));
    Intent recorderIntent = new Intent(this, Recorder.class);
    recorder.setContent(recorderIntent);

    TabSpec player = tabHost.newTabSpec("Player");
    player.setIndicator("Recorder", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_player_tab));
    Intent playerIntent = new Intent(this, Player.class);
    player.setContent(playerIntent);

    tabHost.addTab(settings);
    tabHost.addTab(recorder);
    tabHost.addTab(player);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


 }
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm just blind :)

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you cannot write any statement outside of a method. You can only declare variables.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_syntax.htm

Answer (score 1):

You need  to include all your code starting at

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
```

into a method, ending with `}`